# Geometric Quantization and Wigner Functions

Tags: probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

Geometric quantization of Kähler manifolds successfully leads to the [Segal-Bargmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space), or holomorphic, representation. The polarized sections naturally lead to a distribution weight given by the [Husimi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation), which is everywhere positive. The Husimi function, however, has several disadvantages in analyzing semiclassical behaviour. By reproducing the ordinary marginals, the [Wigner pseudo-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) is much more desirable, no matter its negativity.

The Segal-Bargmann representation arrises from a rather natural polarization choice: the sections are nothing but the holomorphic functions on a (complexified) manifold. Since [inversion formulas for the Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform) are not usually sufficient to recover the Wigner's pseudo-distribution, I am curious about the possibility of devising a geometric quantization procedure, together with a specific polarization, where the weight function is the Wigner pseudo-distribution itself, not Husimi's. This might require weakening pre-quantization and polarization axioms.

Does anyone know anything about it? Any reference? Is this possible?